# Why IDEA copies my resources so slow?

Tags: resources, intellij-idea

I have two maven project one them is fairly small and other one is gigantic.

I am suffering some performance issues at saving and packaging jsp resources (ctrl + shift + f9) into the target directory. For small one, it is usually around 1 seconds, However for the bigger one it is around 6 seconds.

How can I see the details of the compiling process? My primary goal is directly copying the resource into the target directory without any processing.

I have already filed an issue but having some doubts that this is my fault.

Comment: Try [IDEA 12.1 EAP](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+12.1+EAP). If it doesn't help, try disabling [external build](http://img189.imageshack.us/img189/3550/20121206235318.png).

Comment: Disabling external build helped. I will provide details soon.

Comment: Related issue: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-95060. Probably not solved completely.

Comment: I have also filed an issue yesterday: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-102322

Comment: It seems that It might be related to IDEA-95060 but could not be sure. By the way, what are the pros and cons of disabling external build?

Comment: [See this blog post](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/idea/2012/06/brand-new-compiler-mode-in-intellij-idea-12-leda/), non-external build will be gone eventually.